# Ending comes right after beginning in environment?

Tags: environments, texpad

I defined a new environment using

```
\newenvironment{testenv}{
{before}
{after}}
```

Then I use the environment like so:

```
\begin{testenv}
hi
\end{testenv}
```

But my output looks like:
`before after hi`

I am using TexPad - `This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode (preloaded format=latex 2019.10.9)`. Is my environment defined incorrectly? Any idea if there is a way to fix this without expecting an update from TexPad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong! You are specifying only two arguments to `\newenvironment`, but it requires three:

1. the environment's name;
2. the “begin” code;
3. the “end” code.

```latex
\newenvironment{testenv}
  {before}
  {after}
```

is the right syntax.

This is equivalent to

```latex
\newenvironment{testenv}{before}{after}
```

which better highlights the three arguments.